# OMNET++ wireless communication client-server

Tags: simulation, simulator, wireless, omnet++

It's the first time I'm using OMNET++.

I want to start from the very basic stuff to understand how it works.
I successuffly created my first simulation with two hosts continuosly exhanging mesagges (from tictoc example).

What I would like to do now is to simulate a simple client-server wireless communication between one AP and one wireless node. I'm trying to do that using elements from the inet class but I'm stuck and it is not working.

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.base.NetworkConfiguratorBase;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NodeConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.common.packetlevel.RadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211RadioMedium;


//
// TODO documentation
//
network net
{
    string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");
    @display("bgb=620,426");
    submodules:
        wirelessHost1: WirelessHost {
            @display("p=423,164");
        }
        accessPoint1: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=147,197");
        }
        iRadioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            @display("p=523,302");
        }
        iPv4NetworkConfigurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        @display("p=270,324");
        assignDisjunctSubnetAddresses = false;
    }
}
```

and then I created a wirelessHost.cc source file using the tictoc beahviour to make the two nodes communicate.

But it is not working, I get this error:

```
<!> Error in module (inet::IPv4NodeConfigurator) infrastructure.wirelessHost1.networkLayer.configurator (id=13) during network initialization: Configurator module 'configurator' not found (check the 'networkConfiguratorModule' parameter).
```

But before doing something, it was another error about the Access Point (could not find wlan[0] module).
Can someone help me to understand how to configure this model?

**EDIT**
Here's the configuration .ini file

```
[General]
network = infrastructure

#cmdenv-output-file = omnetpp.log
#debug-on-errors = true
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins
#record-eventlog = true

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 600m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 500m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

**.mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility"
**.mobilityType = "StationaryMobility"


# access point
*.accessPoint.wlan[0].mac.address = "004444444444"
*.accessPoint.wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 11


# host1 is associated with AP1 on channel 0
**.wirelessHost1.wlan[0].mgmt.accessPointAddress = "004444444444"
*.wirelessHost1.**.mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtSTASimplified"


# global data rates
**.wlan*.bitrate = 11Mbps

# application level: host1 pings host2
**.numPingApps = 1
*.wirelessHost1.pingApp[0].destAddr = "accessPoint"
*.wirelessHost1.pingApp[0].sendInterval = 10ms
```

but running the simulation I get

```
<!> Error in module (inet::ICMP) infrastructure.wirelessHost1.networkLayer.icmp (id=17) at event #4, t=0.008442657441: check_and_cast(): cannot cast (inet::GenericNetworkProtocolControlInfo*) to type 'inet::IPv4ControlInfo *'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` in network **has to** be named `configurator`. After changing its name your second problem should be resolved too.
Moreover, the name of `RadioMedium` instance module has to be: `radioMedium` (instead of `iRadioMedium`).

**EDIT**
You have made two mistakes.

1. `AccessPoint` **does not have network layer**, because it only relays and sends MAC frames using MAC layer and MAC addresses - like in real network. As a consequence, it does not have an IP address and it is impossible to send ICMP ping to it.
2. `OMNeT++` allows to use module's name instead of an IP address in `ini` file, for example `**.destAddr = "wirelessHost1"`. In your `ini` you are trying to use non existing `accessPoint` instead of `accessPoint1` (which is incorrectly because of the first error).

I suggest adding a new `WirelesHost` (for example `wirelessHost2`) and sending ping towards it, i.e.

```
*.wirelessHost1.pingApp[0].destAddr = "wirelessHost2"
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error
`<!> Error in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio) infrastructure.wirelessHost1.wlan[0].radio (id=29) during network initialization: Module not found on path 'radioMedium' defined by par 'infrastructure.wirelessHost1.wlan[0].radio.radioMediumModule'.`

Comment: That error disappeared but I still can't work with it. Check the question for the Edit